# entity framework model first repository confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I'm not sure if the repository patter is just the most common thing i'm seeing or if it is the best practices for abstracting a layer between the database and the controller.  found some good resources today explaining persistence ignorance and why it's good for unit testing.  However I still feel unclear on a proper entity framework implementation.

my current project, I went about creating the model first.  i can safely say my aggregate roots are:

- Business
- User
- Event
- Invoice

these roots are fairly rich with references to "look-up entities" in the model.  That is to say that my model contains 20 some odd entities, a number of which are used primarily for look-up purposes.  If i were to implement the repository patter,

1. do i need to create a POCO for each entity?
2. Do i ever reference the auto-generated EF classes/entites as attributes of a  repository?
3. Do i always need to use a repository when interacting with the entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do i need to create a POCO for each entity?
   **You should have a plain old CLR object for most entities in your model. You should also have a POCO for each complex type (value object in ddd). Cases where you might not want a POCO for an entity is when creating gerund types for m..n relationships. You can create POCOs for these in EF 4.1, but you don't have to.**
2. Do i ever reference the auto-generated EF classes/entites as attributes of a repository? 
   **The only auto-generated EF classes/entities that I know of in EF 4.1 code first are the dynamic proxies that are created at runtime to populate your navigation and collection properties. You can't and shouldn't try to reference these in any of your source code. Oh, and I think you may be confusing the term "attribute". Attributes are special classes that you can use to decorate classes and methods. Entity classes cannot be used as attributes in this sense.**
3. Do i always need to use a repository when interacting with the entity framework? **No. In fact a lot of people say you shouldn't create a repository until you find that you need one. But if you drive your development from unit tests, you will find need for a repository interface quickly.**

Comment: I went with model first instead of code first. although it seems this is irrelevant. so what i'm gathering is that the entities i created in my .edmx file are actually a proxy? and that i should be creating POCO's for each of these.  I am trying to do this project following TDD.

Comment: I suggest you take a small break, if you can, and at least check out code-first. It actually is model-first, but you build your entity model from classes rather than an edmx design surface. EF 4.1 will then generate the db schema for you. It uses default conventions, but you can change them to sculpt a different schema in the db. Sorry I can't offer much help because I don't use edmx files anymore.

Comment: ok.  so let's say i'm going to refactor for a code-first implementation.  i create my POCO's first.  I have looked over a couple examples of code first, and i see two different things. implementation of the context using DbContext and using Object Context.  What are some arguments to choose one over the other.  i feel like there is some magic happening here by not using an edmx to generate the db schema.  how does the code-first approach generate a schema?

Comment: I suggest you use DbContext. ObjectContext I believe comes from older versions of EF and is there to help bridge for people who started pre-4.1. Code first generates the schema using something called a DbModelBuilder. It has built-in conventions which you can remove, and you define deviations from the convention schema using methods on an instance of DbModelBuilder.

Comment: if i want to make this part of my project reusable and put it in a separate project, does that violate some sort of best practice?

Answer (score -1):

In Entity Framework, your DataContext class **is** a repository, and one over which you have a lot of control with EF 4.1.  I don't in any way mean to sound flippant, because this is a really good question with a lot of bad answers.

When you use EF, you're already using the repository pattern.  Take advantage of that and write less code.  Resist the urge to over-architect.

1) This depends on how your behavioral model (your objects) translates to your data model (your database.)  There is truly no prescriptive guidance.

2) EF already does this, if by attributes you mean properties.

3) You already do.  :-)

Stephen

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree that EF is a repository pattern, because you cannot unit test and inject your own data into it -- it needs to connect to a database. It definitely is a UnitOfWork pattern, and it is like a repository pattern. However, you cannot mock your IDbSet properties without wrapping them in an interface.